# Broken or misconfigured gammu-smsd on Kali

Tags: kali-linux

I have a broken or misconfigured gammu-smsd on Kali. I tried the usual stuff to auto fix but keep getting these errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:gammu-smsd E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

gammu-smsd.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started 

~/systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service:9: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-sms
```

Comment: i googled `the usual stuff`, but i did not get any linux related hits ... what did you try?

Comment: usual apt stuff upgrade/date purge everything i could find but if you know of anything else i'd try because its going on a cpl weeks like this i dont want to reinstall the whole os because im sure its something minor

Comment: Fix question by editing question. Don't leave errata in comments.

Comment: What is your experience level with Gnu/Linux?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `/lib/systemd/system/gammu-smsd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/` and edit it. Change line 9:

   ```
   ExecStart=${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}/gammu-smsd --pid=/var/run/gammu-smsd.pid --daemon
   ```

   so that instead of `${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}` you have the absolute directory that contains `gammu-smsd`. (I don't know what that is, as I don't have the package installed on any of my systems.)
2. Run `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Run `dpkg-reconfigure -a`
4. Submit a bug report to Kali describing this issue

Comment: To find the directory, I believe you would run: `which gammu-smsd`